# Get days until date based on timezone on phone

Tags: android, datetime

I´ve been trying to figure this out for a while but can not wrap my head around it.
I´m working on an android app and i want to display left to a specific date, and i want the number of days based on what time zone i have set on my phone.

I have Joda Time in my app and the information i have is for example:

**2013-05-05 9.00PM** the time is in PST (GMT-8) timezone, i have no clue how to do this and i have searched both on google and SO but can not get a clear answer.

**EDIT**

I managed to solve my problem with code found here on SO

```
String dateString = airDate + " " + airTime.toUpperCase();

                SimpleDateFormat sourceFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd K:mma");
                sourceFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-8"));

                Date parsed;

                parsed = sourceFormat.parse(dateString);
                TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
                SimpleDateFormat destFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                destFormat.setTimeZone(tz);

                result = destFormat.format(parsed);
```

However I found out that the times i first got isn´t correct and I now get the time zone in the format **GMT-5 +DST**. And I dont´t know what to do with the +DST if setting the time to 20:00 and using GMT-5 in my TimeZone.getTimeZone the time returned is 22:00 which is "wrong" since I live in sweden. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Did u check on SimpleDateFormat and TimeZone classes?

Answer (score 0):

If you could settle for a string that looks like "in 2 days", then you should be able to use [`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString%28long,%20long,%20long,%20int%29).

Comment: I tried combing your suggestion with the suggestion by Daniel. I converted my date time to milliseconds an used as parameter in DateUtils.getRelativeTime..... Still got the "original" date thou. I don't know if this is the right approach either.